# Convergence of $(108, -18, 3,-1/2 ,\ldots)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can we determine whether the sequence $(108,-18,3,-1/2,\ldots)$ converges or diverges? If it converges, what is its limit?

Comment: How does the sequence continue? What comes next, and why?

Comment: I guess we are invited to guess the general rule. Note that (so far) we are multiplying by $-\frac{1}{6}$ each time.

Answer (score 3):

The sequence converges to $0$ as $(-\frac16)^n\to 0$.

Comment: so the limit would be zero

Comment: arright thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Your sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=0,1,\ldots}$ is of the form
$$x_n = \dfrac{108}{(-6)^n}$$
Can you now guess the limit?